# ¿Qué quiere decir 'mosquito' en Colombia y America Latina?

Tags: colombia, animales

¿Es igual a 'zancudo' o tiene otro significado, otro insecto?

En el diccionario solo dice que 'mosquito' es como 'mosquito' en inglés. Pero si la memoria no me falla alguien en Colombia me dijo una vez que la palabra significa algo como una mosca pequeña. ¿Tal vez una mosca de fruta? Pero creo que el insecto de lo que hablaba tambien pica. ¿Qué puede ser?

Comment: En México es un insecto pequeñito (mosco pequeño), y no es equivalente a zancudo.

Comment: En Chile es como en Colombia, la mosca pequeña como la de las frutas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mosquito en Colombia es un insecto volador pequeño equivalente al diminutivo de mosca pero no es un zancudo.

Algunos pican a los humanos y otros simplemente vuelan sobre la basura o las frutas maduras.

Entre los "mosquitos" que pican a los humanos hay uno muy notable que se llama **jején** que es gris o casi negro, del tamaño de la cabeza de un alfiler o aproximadamente 2 mm cuya picadura es bastante dolorosa y genera ardor y molestias hasta por varias semanas.

[image]

Los otros mosquitos son los que aparecen junto a las frutas maduras y también son de entre 2 y 3 mm pero su color es mas rojizo y son fáciles de distinguir de la "mosca de la fruta" la cual siempre mantiene sus alas abiertas y es un poco más grande.

[image]

Como se ve en ambas imágenes, estos animalitos tiene forma redondeada y compacta como de mosca pequeña muy diferente a la forma alargada y de patas largas de los zancudos.

Algunas personas usan la palabra *mosco* en masculino para referirse genéricamente a todos los insectos voladores pequeños pero la gran mayoría distinguen claramente las moscas, los mosquitos y los zancudos.

---

Por comparación anexo imagen de "mosca de la fruta" y zancudo
[image] [image]